# Dedicated nodes for Namespace

Tags: kubernetes

In Kubernetes, we have multiple environments, separated by different namespace. I want to ensure that one set of nodes are only used by a specific namespace/environment.

1. Nodes of specific labels should reject all pods, which doesn't belong to a namespace
2. Pods from a specific namespace should always choose nodes with the labels configured.

What is the way to achieve it? Heard about mutating webhook admission controllers, Anybody has a sample, to see how it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign a namespace to certain nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487333/how-to-assign-a-namespace-to-certain-nodes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use mutating webhook to mutate an incoming pod request from a specific namespace to add [node affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity) or [node selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) in the pod spec.

An example of `nodeSelector` admission controller [here](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/admission/podnodeselector?tab=doc). Full [guide](https://www.mgasch.com/post/podnodesel/) on how to use it.

**Prepare API Server**

Assuming your cluster has been deployed with kubeadm, the kube-apiserver.yaml file is the configuration manifest for the Kubernetes API server. It is located in /etc/kubernetes/manifests. Add the PodNodeSelector admission controller in the --admission-control= flag

Then add a label to a node

```
kubectl label node kubeprod01 env=production
```

Then use that label in the annotation of the namespace.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  annotations:
    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/node-selector: env=production
```

An example of adding node affinity via mutating webhook.

```
func mutatePods(ar v1beta1.AdmissionReview, o *options) *v1beta1.AdmissionResponse {
    var reviewResponse = &v1beta1.AdmissionResponse{
        Allowed: true,
    }

    podResource := metav1.GroupVersionResource{Group: "", Version: "v1", Resource: "pods"}
    if ar.Request.Resource != podResource {
        glog.Errorf("expect resource to be %s", podResource)
        return nil
    }

    raw := ar.Request.Object.Raw
    pod := v1.Pod{}
    // glog.V(2).Infof("Object: %v", string(raw))
    if err := json.Unmarshal(raw, &pod); err != nil {
        glog.Error(err)
        return nil
    }

    addPodAffinityPatch := fmt.Sprintf(`[
         {"op":"add","path":"/spec/affinity","value":{"nodeAffinity":{"preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution":[{"preference":{"matchExpressions":[{"key":"%s","operator":"NotIn","values":["%s"]}]},"weight":1}]}}}
    ]`, o.PodAffinityKey, o.PodAffinityValue)

    glog.V(2).Infof("patching pod")
    reviewResponse.Patch = []byte(addPodAffinityPatch)
    pt := v1beta1.PatchTypeJSONPatch
    reviewResponse.PatchType = &pt

    return reviewResponse
}
```

Comment: I've recently open-sourced a mutating webhook that does that out of the box: https://github.com/idgenchev/namespace-node-affinity :)

Answer (score 2):

It can be done via node-selector annotation in the namespace, see an example [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/77687#issuecomment-491396973)

Comment: This approach is described in details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62938949/151641 but I don't think it is sufficient without taints.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure a set of nodes is **dedicated only** to the resources in a namespace, you should use a combination of:

- `podSelector` *to force scheduling of resources only on nodes of the set*
- and a `taint` *to deny scheduling of any other resource not in the namespace on the nodes of the set*

How to create a namespace dedicated to use only a set of nodes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74617601/5482942

---

Also, I found it useful to read the [motivations for using namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/namespaces/#understanding-the-motivation-for-using-namespaces).

Indeed, in general, it is not recommended to have multiple environments (dev, test, staging, prod) in the same k8s cluster.

The best practice is to use dedicated clusters for each environment.

To save on costs, you can take the comprises of using:

- 1 cluster: dev, test, staging
- 1 cluster: prod