# How to create namespace with specific node pool

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

We are trying to create namespace with specific node pool. How to achieve that on Azure Kubernetes?

```
error: Unable to create namespace with specific node pool.
Ex: namespace for user nodepool1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign a namespace to certain nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487333/how-to-assign-a-namespace-to-certain-nodes)

Answer (score 3):

Posting this as a community wiki, feel free to edit and expend it.

As [Luca Ghersi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5951680/luca-ghersi) mentioned in comments, it's possible to have namespaces assigned to a specific nodes. For this matter there's an admission controller `PodNodeSelector` (you can read about it on [kubernetes official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#podnodeselector)).

In short words:

> This admission controller defaults and limits what node selectors may
> be used within a namespace by reading a namespace annotation and a
> global configuration.

Based on [Azure FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#what-kubernetes-admission-controllers-does-aks-support-can-admission-controllers-be-added-or-removed), Azure AKS has this admission controller enabled by default.

```
AKS supports the following admission controllers:

- NamespaceLifecycle
- LimitRanger
- ServiceAccount
- DefaultStorageClass
- DefaultTolerationSeconds
- MutatingAdmissionWebhook
- ValidatingAdmissionWebhook
- ResourceQuota
- PodNodeSelector
- PodTolerationRestriction
- ExtendedResourceToleration

Currently, you can't modify the list of admission controllers in AKS.
```