# k3s node restriction for namespace

Tags: plugins, namespaces, restriction, k3s

I would like to ask you where should I look for some information on how to force deployments from some namespace to run on specific nodes in the k3s cluster.

I found this: [How to assign a namespace to certain nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52487333/how-to-assign-a-namespace-to-certain-nodes).

Which is the simmilar issue that I have or want.

But I didn't have luck of finding this PodNodeSelector plugin in my k3s cluster. Can you point me where should I look, because I tried documentation and didn't find what I was looking for.

Desired state:

1. testing namespace - able to do
2. nodes tagged test - able to do
3. kube config to namespace - able to do
4. allow deployments to run just on the tagged nodes - asking

Thanks for your suggestions and have a nice day.

Comment: Ok, solved by me... You have to enable admission plugins within the installation process. `shell: curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_EXEC=
                                                          --kube-apiserver-arg enable-admission-plugins=PodNodeSelector"
                                                          sh -` . Then you are able to add one line to the namespace: `annotations:
    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/node-selector: hellen=yes`

Comment: you should put that as an actual answer instead of as a comment. i almost ignored the question considering as unanswered